# Efficiently find the next item in a sequence to exceed some bounds

Tags: algorithms, efficiency

I have a bounded sequence of integers, and for each element, I want to know if the sequence next goes some distance above that element, below that element, or neither.  This is straightforward in quadratic time; is there a more efficient solution?

More formally, I have $N$ integers $a_i \in [0, R)$, upper and lower offsets $U, L \in [0, R)$, and a window $W < N$.  For each $i$, define:

$$
f(i) = \min\left\{j \in (i, i + W] \mid x_{j} < x_{i} - L \lor x_{j} > x_{i} + U\right\}
$$

That is, $f(i)$ is the index of the first element after $i$ to go outside the bounds, or $nil$ if there is no such element.

For example, with $R = 6, U = 2, L = 1, W = 3,$ the sequence

$[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0] \to [3, 4, 5, nil, nil, 7, 8, 9, 10, nil, nil]$

Here is the simple $O(N W)$ solution in Python:

```
def breakout(a: Sequence[int], upper: int, lower: int, window: int) -> Sequence[Optional[int]]:
    """For each `a[i]`, compute the (index of the) next element (within a 
    `window`) to go above `a[i] + upper` or below `a[i] - lower`."""
    assert upper >= 0 and lower >= 0 and window >= 0
    result = [None] * len(a)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(i + 1, min(i + window + 1, len(a))):
            if a[j] < a[i] - lower or a[j] > a[i] + upper:
                result[i] = j
                break
    return result
```

Does this problem have a name or a more efficient solution?

Comment: Try using a balanced binary tree (or equivalent data structure) to store (part of) the last $W$ elements.